# Share data between two app using SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am sharing data between two my app, this is my code for get the data from the shared pref in app **A**

```
    try {
        final Context mContext = createPackageContext("com.example.demo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        final String val = mContext.getSharedPreferences("pref_name",Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString(MY_KEY,"");
        Log.e("sharedtest",val);
        finish();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

this code is inside the onCreate() method, I don't have any more code anywhere. My problem is that, if I save the some value in my app **B** and than start my app **A** the saved data were correctly retrieved at first time, after retrieving the data my activity were finishing (I have only one activity), and if I start my launcher icon and start my app **A**, there is no updated data(it is the same), which where changed from app **B**.

also if I kill my app from system app settings and launch it like first time launch updated data is here, every data change needs my app killing from settings, how can I fix that? what I'm missing?

Comment: The more correct solution to this will be to using content provider rather than using shared references.

Comment: I need only one string, why don't use preference?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found solution it may be a trick but it works fine for me,
after my app **A** finishes its job, I'm calling the system exit method.

```
 System.exit(1);
```

it makes app "A" to be exit and finish job completely

After that I had the latest updated data in my preferences

Comment: Lol, use `finish()`

Comment: You shouldn't use System.exit in Android context. As said Florescu, use Finish()

Comment: I'm calling this from service, when service is running activity is already dead, after service has been started I'm calling finish from Activity